# How to catch errors as exceptions in php?

Tags: php, exception

I'm trying to ensure that my errors are caught as exceptions but something isn't connecting.

**I'm using this error handler definition:**

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

**I have a my_file.php with a failing require_once on purpose**

```
require_once('name_of_file_which_does_not_exist.php');
```

**Now, when I load my_file.php, I was hoping to catch the include error as an exception.**

```
try {
    require_once('my_file.php');
} catch(ErrorException $exception) {
    echo '<br>'.$exception->getMessage();
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting `Uncaught ErrorException` on name_of_file_which_does_not_exist.php and the request dies. Since it is the `ErrorException`, I believe the handler is defined correctly. What's missing?

I'm not married to this particular solution. I just would rather deal with errors as exceptions that I catch and log, rather than check my directory for the error_log file. If there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

**Update**

I've upgraded to PHP version 8.1 and now it's working for me. I was on a version 7 before. Not sure which particular one. Once I saw it working, I removed the custom error handler and tried to rely on simply catching Throwable. The request didn't die but the error_log file was still created. When I added the custom error handler back, the request succeeds, exception is reported correctly in my log and there's no error_log file generated.

So this exercise tells me that we do need the custom error handler and ability to catch a failing `require_once` is dependent on the version of PHP. Can someone confirm this conclusion?

Comment: What do you expect to get? Your error handler just throws an ErrorException, which I don't see you catching anywhere? All you've done is creating an error handler that will always throw an ErrorException on the errors it gets.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

} catch (Throwable $throwable) {
  // Error and Exception handling goes here.
}
```

If you want to handle Exceptions and Errors differently:

```
try {

} catch (Exception $exception) {
  // Exception handling goes here.
} catch (Error $error) {
  // Error handling goes here.
}
```

This works because both Error and Exceptions inherit from the Throwable class.